# Fetch particular elements in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Here's my list :

```
list = [(a,1,2),(b,3,4),(c,5,6),(d,7,8),(e,9,10)]
```

I want to fetch the second element of the first three tuples. In this case it would be 1,3,5. Here's what I did :

```
[item[1] for item in list]
```

But this would return all the elements, while I only need the first three. How do I do that?

Comment: You can slice your `list`:


    `[item[1] for item in list[:3]]`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact number, you can use the range() function:

```
[list[i][1] for i in range(3)]
```